# Form values remain after refresh

Tags: forms, refresh

Hey guys, I've seen some other post similar to this, but nothing suggested in those post has worked for me, so I'll ask again here.

I've got a really basic form. If a user fill out the form partially, then hits refresh, the page reloads and all styles are reset, but instead of having the default text in the form input fields (ie: 'Required') the values from before the refresh are there. I know this is an odd case, that's unlikely to happen, but I'd still like to know why this is happening and how to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

`<form autocomplete="off">`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely useful Firefox feature.

You should not try to prevent it.